# Include WorkItems in TFS Build Report

Tags: tfs, build, build-process

I want to include Work Items in my Build Report. Like the Change Set is displaying all the Change Sets Made by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you associate the Work items with the changeset during check-in? It should show you the work items like in the image below.

[image]